# Vertical Alignment of `lim`/`sup`/`inf`

Tags: vertical-alignment, alignment, vertical

Personally, I'm not keen on the look of `$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x + an)$`. (Why does *TeX*.SE not compile TeX??) It looks weird to me having `lim` on the same level as `f` yet the `n \to \infty` lower down. (I realise that it is different in `\textstyle` it looks different.)

I would like to try having the `\lim_{n \to \infty}` vertically aligned so that its centre (vertically) is in line with the horizontal bar from `+` -- or something close to this.

Hopefully the following pictures describe what I want! I want the two blue lines (which are supposed to be the halfway points of the vertical red lines) in the second one to be vertically aligned with each other. (In the first, the base of `lim` and of `f` are vertically aligned.)

[image]

[image]

I guess this can be bodged with with lots of `\vspace{+/-}` commands. I would be interested in a 'proper' solution to this, though!
Use of packages is permissible, but they should be compatible with standard `ams---` as well as `mathtools`.

Comment: Why does TeX.SE not compile TeX? Because this is a TeX site and we want to discuss the code, so having it automatically rendered would be quite useless. See [this meta question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1272/82917).

Comment: I think I must be misinterpreting what you're trying to do - could you provide a picture of any article or book which looks like the desired output from your proposed amendment? If you don't want {n\to \infty} in a subscript, you could simply not put it in one?

Comment: "Would be quite useless". I would like to show what I mean, and this would be *very useful* if it compiled. Of course, we need the compiling to be *optional*: automatic compiling would be terrible as then code couldn't be shown. But there could certainly be some way to make it possible to engage manually

Comment: As I was writing that someone wants _exactly_ what I was suggestion people would want; how convenient for my argument =P -- Now I'll go and take a snapshot, save that image and then upload -- shame I can't just write $$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} $$$ or something like that :(

Comment: Perhaps $\vcenter{\hbox{$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}$}} f(x+an)$ is closer to what you want? Both the tex and the output are unsightly though..

Comment: I agree with @campa. While showing a TeX output is often important, most of the code in questions is not compileable or not showing the intended ouput (at least for newcomers) . Moreover, some users have issues with very specific classes, which may not be widely accessible, with no way to reproduce results. Also, some issues are very system, install, or distribution specific, with no way to ensure the output on the site reproduces the actual issue. To sum things up, IMHO there are far too many different situations to consider that automatic (or even optional) compilation would be relevant

Comment: The reason is that's not what people do.

Comment: I think a more fundamental problem with compiling is that MathJaX only handles the more basic TeX syntax.  So then we'd have to figure out if something isn't working because they don't understand TeX or if their code works in TeX but not in MathJaX.  (As you were writing, someone posted asking for a picture of the output you wanted.  $$$\lim_n f$$$ would only create a picture of the existing functionality, which wouldn't explain what you wanted.)

Comment: @Teepeemm Actually, that was me who added the picture =P -- but I agree one would just use MathJaX or something like that, and so there is a potential for people to write something which compiles differently in MathJaX to their particular TeX set-up (eg if they're using a certain class). This is certainly a strong argument against having compilation! (+1). What _is not_ is the claim that it would be "useless". (Indeed, the previous argument basically only holds if it would be useful!)

Comment: Oh boy, I didn't expect (and it was not my intention) to raise such a fuss with my comment. In hindsight, I admit that "useless" was no happy word choice. Counter-productive might have been a better alternative.

Comment: @campa I think `Teepeemm` makes a good argument for why it could be counter-productive!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `\raisedlim` command outputs a `\lim` in display style, raised to the height of the horizontal bar of a `+` symbol.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\halfplusheight}
\setlength{\halfplusheight}{\totalheightof{\(+\)} * \real{.5} - \depthof{\(+\)}}
\newcommand{\raisedlim}[1]{%
    \mathop{\raisebox{\halfplusheight}{\(\displaystyle\lim_{#1}\)}}%
}
\begin{document}
\( \displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} f(x + an) 
   \qquad 
   \raisedlim{n\to\infty} f(x + an) \)
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a nice simple solution, thanks! `egreg`'s appears to allow more general vertical centring, so I may end up using theirs; but for what I asked, yours is great! :)

Comment: @SamT Indeed egreg's answer is surely better. It fascinates me how much some people know about LaTeX around here.

Comment: It is pretty amazing! I always try to get general answers, and ask general questions, to learn as much as I can. There's so much to learn though -- and as you say, some (eg `egreg`!) are so knowledgeable!

Comment: After using both this answer and the one due to egreg, I have found yours more suitable for my purposes -- specifically the fact that it moves `lim` the same amount each time, even if the subscript is slightly larger. As such, I have swapped the accepted answer to this one. Thank you again for your time and help! :)

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this (top row)?

[image]

Now that you see it in action, you surely don't want to use it: it's meaningless.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\lim}{e{_}}{%
  \mathop{\vcenter{\hbox{$\displaystyle
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}
      {\operatorname*{lim}}
      {\operatorname*{lim}_{#1}}
    $}}}%
  \nolimits
}

\begin{document}

\[
\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x+an) \tag{NEW}
\]

\[
\operatorname*{lim}_{n\to\infty}f(x+an) \tag{STANDARD}
\]

\end{document}
```

An image at random from the 1926 volume of Acta Mathematica, a journal which always had very high standards in mathematical typesetting.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "meaningless"? :) -- what is meaningless? I plan to use this with more complicated expressions than just `f(x+an)` -- in particular, ones which are quite 'tall'. The standard then looks very jarring when the `n \to \infty` is low and the next bit is tall!

Comment: @SamT There should be a reason if everybody does like the standard except for you!

Comment: Should be a reason for changing it, do you mean? :) -- this is explained in my comment above. And can you provide a reference for your claim that everybody likes the standard? ;-) -- I know a lot of people who don't like things that tex does, but don't care enough to find out how to change them. I've found this annoying for years, but not bothered me much. I'm interested in learning more about tex though, and this would be an improvement, so I thought why not ask! :)

Comment: @SamT Take any book from your shelf. It's not a question of letting TeX do as it wants: it's tha TeX does like *everybody* does.

Comment: Given the amount of hate I see for the default tex behaviour, I'm going to have to disagree with you there. *However*, I don't have real evidence to provide on this matter, and I'm guessing that you don't have evidence to back up your claims; so let's politely agree to disagree :)

Comment: To be honest, \displaystyle should generally be reserved for actual displays anyway. The \nolimits variant (the default in textstyle) is more suitable for text. I can't imagine this new version will look well within a wall of text? Especially if "n" were instead a "j" etc. Latex might push apart text lines to make your new limit fit, resulting in uneven spacing between lines.

Comment: @SamT I *do* have evidence. I added an image: where would you place “lim” in that case?

Comment: @Fintan Yes, sure, I am only using it in a display equation :) -- I just put `\displaystyle` to emphasise that I wanted it display :)

Comment: @egreg Less of a concern would be where to place the `lim` and more how quickly I could fire whoever typeset that affront to the senses, haha! Obviously far more preferable would be `\[ \lim_{z \to 0} \frac1z \int_0^z F_1(z) dz \]` (ignoring the fact that they've put `z` as both an integral limit and the integration dummy variable!). Even nicer, in my opinion, although not all will agree, would be `\[ \lim_{z \to 0} \textstyle \frac1z \int_0^z F_1(z) dz \]` -- and when using the latter, your change to `lim` makes it even nicer :)

Comment: After using both this answer and the one due to @Vincent, I have found Vincent's more suitable for my purposes -- specifically the fact that it moves `lim` the same amount each time, even if the subscript is slightly larger. As such, I have swapped the accepted answer to that of Vincent. Your answer will still be helpful in some situations though, of that I am sure. Thank you again for your time and help! :)

Comment: @SamT Well, I don't think anybody else than you will use it. `;-)` Just use the standard way and your readers will be grateful. `:-)`